# Boot from non ESP

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I am looking to boot an EFI file on a partition on my hard drive that is not the EFI System Partition. In other words, I have a boot partition that has a .efi file I wish to boot from, but it is on 0,3 as opposed to 0,0. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly speaking, it's possible, but only if certain conditions are met:

- The EFI must be able to read the partition. This means that either the partition must use FAT (or HFS+ on Macs) or you must install an EFI filesystem driver for the filesystem in question.
- You must be able to direct the firmware's boot process to the file. This is officially supported for files on ESPs, and because it's legal to have multiple ESPs, if the partition uses FAT, you can easily give it the ESP type code and it should work. In practice, many EFIs also support booting from non-ESP FAT partitions, too. If the filesystem is not FAT, though, the only way I know of to get this to work is to use [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) (which is discontinued) or [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind) (which is its successor) and a suitable filesystem driver as a boot manager. These programs will redirect the boot process to any `.efi` file on any filesystem that the EFI can read.

If you need more help, please post more details, such as what filesystem is used on the target partition, what boot manager(s) or boot loader(s) you're using, and why you want to install the target `.efi` file to the partition in question rather than to the ESP. Knowing the details might suggest a solution, or another way to do what you want to do. In most cases, installing the `.efi` file to the ESP is the simplest solution. The main reason I know of to want to launch a `.efi` file from something other than the ESP is if it's ELILO, gummiboot, or some other Linux boot loader that must load a Linux kernel from its own partition. In this case, it might make sense to mount the ESP at `/boot` in Linux, which results in Linux kernels being stored on the ESP by default.